# Basic FTC question.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In a paper I'm reading, they state without proof that if $\phi\in C_c^\infty(R^2)$, then

$|\phi(x_1,x_2)|\le \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\
\phi_{x_1}(t,x_2)|dt$

I understand one should use the fundamental theorem of calculus but I cannot justify the constant.

Comment: By $\phi_{x_1}(t, x_2)$ do you mean the derivative of $\phi$ with respect to its first argument, or something else entirely?

Comment: Without the constant, you have $|f(x)|=\left|\int_{-\infty}^x f'(t)dt \right|\leq \int_{-\infty}^x \left|f'(t) \right|dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|f'(t) \right|dt.$  This only uses compact support on the left side.  I think the constant might come from splitting the integral up at where $f$ takes it's max and using compact support on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $x_2$ is only used as a constant, and so we can consider a function of one variable, where the analogous statement is $|f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f'(t)|dt$

Because $f$ is compactly supported, $f(x)=f'(x)=0$ for all sufficiently large values of $|x|$, and so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f'(t)dt$.  Similarly, $-f(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty} f'(t)dt$.  Combining the two, we have

$  2|f(x)|=\left|\int_{-\infty}^x f'(t)dt \right|+\left|\int_{x}^{\infty} f'(t)dt \right|\leq \int_{-\infty}^x \left|f'(t) \right|dt +\int_{x}^{\infty} \left|f'(t) \right|dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|f'(t) \right|dt. $